# What's the posessive form of address

Tags: possessives

What would be the correct possessive form of *address*? I was working on a project, and one of the error messages was

> You can't spoof the address' domain

A colleague of mine pointed out that this isn't how it's supposed to be spelled, and suggested *address's*. That looks odd to me, so maybe it could be *addresses*, but that's also the plural.

Comment: In other languages, such as German, it is acceptable to drop the additional s if the word already ends in s. Not sure if that is the origin of your confusion.

Comment: Different style guides have different preferences when possessing words in _-s_. Most would prefer your colleague’s way; some would prefer yours.

Comment: This may only work if you're a native English speaker, but I understood the rule to be that it is written as one would say it, i.e. "the peoples' domain" and "the address's domain"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your colleague is correct.

However, if you still don't feel comfortable with it, you can get around the issue with a simple rewording:

> *You can't spoof the domain of the address*

Comment: @painfulenglish - I assume you meant to direct that comment at the OP...?

Comment: you are right, sorry about that.